# Let $a$ and $b$ be two integers, not both zero. Consider the two sets $S = \{k ∈ Z : ∃ x, y ∈ Z, ax + by = k\}, T =\{k∈Z:(k|a)∧(k|b)\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Review question I need help with.

Let $a$ and $b$ be two integers, not both zero. Consider the two sets
$$S = \{k ∈ \mathbb{Z} : ∃ x, y ∈ \mathbb{Z}, ax + by = k\}$$
$$T =\{k∈\mathbb{Z}:(k|a)∧(k|b)\}$$
List all the elements of the set S ∩ T and prove that your answer is correct.

Comment: What  do you know about the GCD of $a$ and $b$? Have you seen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Suppose that $k\in S$, and $x$ and $y$ are integers such that $ax+by=k$. If $d\in T$, then $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$, so $d\mid k$. In other words, every member of $S$ is divisible by every common divisor of $a$ and $b$. Now use [Bézout’s lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), which says that $\gcd(a,b)\in S$. (If you’re reviewing, it might be a good idea to review the proof of Bézout’s lemma, too.)

Comment: Is it possible to avoid Bezout's lemma in this question?

Comment: @Jake: I don’t think so. I think that any argument that doesn’t use it explicitly will essentially be a proof of it.

Comment: Because I haven't been taught Bezout's lemma in my course.

Comment: @Jake: Then let $\delta$ be the smallest positive member of $S$, let $d=\gcd(a,b)$, and try to show that $\delta=d$. You already know that $d\mid\delta$; try to show that $\delta\mid d$. Use the division algorithm to write $d=q\delta+r$ with $0\le r<\delta$, and show that $r=0$.